# How closely correlated is the level of an snRNA with the level of its corresponding snRNP?

Tags: rna, pcr

Let's say I am growing cells under two conditions, and let's say I measure U1 snRNA levels in both using digital PCR.  If the U1 snRNA level is reduced in one sample, how safe is it to say that U1 snRNP is also reduced in that sample?